# maximum flow problem

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently reviewing for a test and on our study guide is a problem having to do with maximum flow and I just cant seem to figure out how to do it since there is no good examples in my text book. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Somewhere on this page you will find the word, "Related", and under it a list of questions previously asked here, and I wouldn't be surprised to find a detailed answer to the question of how to find a maximal flow in a network at at least one of those links. Have a look!

Comment: For example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90812/how-to-calculate-the-maximum-flow-in-this-graph-by-the-edmonds-karp-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know what algorithm(s) you’ve been taught, if any, but this one can be done by inspection. Since the indegree of $z$ is $11$, the maximum flow cannot be greater than $11$. Working back from $z$ and experimenting a bit, I find the flow shown below, whose value **is** $11$. You can easily check that it’s feasible: the flow into each node other than the source $a$ and the sink $z$ is equal to the flow out, and the flow along each edge is at most the capacity of that edge.

```
                          4  
                     b ------- c  
                    /|        /|\  
                  6/ |       / | \5  
                  /  |      /  |  \  
                 /   |     /   |   \  
                a    |2   /    |2   z  
                 \   |   /3    |   /  
                  \  |  /      |  /  
                  5\ | /       | /6  
                    \|/        |/  
                     d ------- e  
                          4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mathematica `FindMaximumFlow` to verify your answer.

```
g = Graph[{"a" -> "b", "a" -> "d", "b" -> "c", "b" -> "d", "c" -> "e",
     "c" -> "z", "d" -> "c", "d" -> "e", "e" -> "z"}, 
   EdgeCapacity -> {7, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 4, 6}, 
   EdgeWeight -> {7, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 4, 6}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding"];
GraphPlot[g]
source = "a";
sink = "z";
\[ScriptCapitalF] = FindMaximumFlow[g, source, sink, "OptimumFlowData"]
\[ScriptCapitalF]["FlowValue"]
\[ScriptCapitalF]["FlowGraph"]
```

the Maximum FlowValue is $11$